# How to make different structure of JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving data from 2 tables: 1) for home banners and 2) for hot deals.
And after that, I am making REST API from it.
But i am getting data in json like this:

```
 [
    {
        "homuri": "/Home/Banner/activity.png"
    },
    {
        "homuri": "/Home/Banner/fitness.png"
    },   
    {
        "hotdeal": "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal1.png"
    },
    {
        "hotdeal": "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal2.png"
    },
    {
        "hotdeal": "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal3.png"
    },

]
```

But I want my json structure like this:

```
[
        "banner":{
            "homuri": "/Home/Banner/activity.png",
            "homuri": "/Home/Banner/fitness.png"
        },   
        "hotdeals":{
            "hotdeal": "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal1.png",
            "hotdeal": "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal2.png",
            "hotdeal": "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal3.png",
        },    
]
```

How to achieve this? 
and how can I access all these values in HTML?
Below I am attaching my code:

```
<?php

    include('dbconn.php');
    $request=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    $data=array();
    switch($request)
    {
        case 'GET':
            response(getData());                        
    }

    function getData()
    {
        global $conn;
        @$col=$_GET['col'];

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select strHomeBannerUri as homuri from tblhomebannerdetails");

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $data[]=array("homuri"=>$row['homuri']);            
        }

        if($col=="pop")
        {
            $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select nHotrDealImageUri as hotdeal from tblhotdealimages");

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $data[]=array("hotdeal"=>$row['hotdeal']);          
        }

        }           
        return $data;           
    }


    function response($data)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempted source code on how you grouped the data by "hotdeal" and "banner".

Comment: @Progman I tried many things but all was wrong. And Stackoverflow is not allowing me to paste more code.

Comment: The way you want your data to look is not valid JSON. It should be a list of STRINGS and not a object of objects (as they all have similar keys).

Comment: if that source `json` is `really` your json (eg not some personal interpretation of what you get), it is invalid and wont decode. Neither is your output json specificaiton;

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I followed some tutorial from internet about REST API and got this. And i am able to fetch the data but not in desired way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you want your JSON to look will not work - you cannot use one key multiple times in the same "nesting-level".

```
function getData()
{
    global $conn;
    @$col=$_GET['col'];

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select strHomeBannerUri as homuri from tblhomebannerdetails");

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $data['homeuri'][]= $row['homuri'];            
    }

    if($col=="pop")
    {
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select nHotrDealImageUri as hotdeal from tblhotdealimages");

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $data['hotdeals'][]= $row['hotdeal'];          
    }

    }           
    return $data;           
}
```

Could do the trick - you have some problems in your logic, you should check yourself on how to write and modify arrays in PHP.
When you've done that, please check JSON and how to structure JSON Objects/Lists.

The code above should return something like

```
{
    "banner":[
        "/Home/Banner/activity.png",
        "/Home/Banner/fitness.png"
    ],   
    "hotdeals":[
        "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal1.png",
        "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal2.png",
        "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal3.png"
    ],    
}
```

Comment: Its working, but what if suppose i want to retrieved one more column in my 2nd query?

Comment: select nHotrDealImageUri as hotdeal,nBusinessDetailsId as bid from tblhotdealimages

Comment: What stops you from doing that in your select-statement? Or do you want to add it to the response?
Then you should do things like
    `$data['hotdeals'][]= ['uri' => $row['hotdeal'], 'id' => $row['bid']];`

You should really put some effort in understanding how to define JSON Code - Objects and Lists should be some keywords for you.